# print binary file

Tags: c

Say you have a file dog.txt

```
The
quick
brown
fox
jumps
over
the
lazy
dog
```

You can print the lines like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
int 
main (void)
{
  char buf[10];
  FILE *fp = fopen ("dog.txt", "r");
  while (fgets (buf, sizeof buf, fp))
    printf ("%s", buf);
  return 0;
}
```

But what if each "line" was separated by a null character (`\0`), instead of a newline (`\n`)? How would you print each "line" ?

Comment: Yep, `iostream` is only available on C++. Didn't see the C tag, sorry. I'll just post it here in case someone wonder how to solve this problem in C++: `ifstream fp("dog.txt"); while (fp.getline(buf, 10, '\0')) { ... }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a trimmed down version of
[WhozCraig’s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1322972)
deleted answer

If all you want to do is dump data from the input file to stdout, replacing any imbedded null-chars (0) with newlines, then just do that. read-ahead buffering and such is honestly overkill for the simplicity of this problem, and besides, the fopen/fread/etc.. family already buffers for you.

Note: this assumes *exactly* what the OP specified, the this is otherwise a reagular "text" file save for the oddity that imbedded null-chars (0)'s should be treated as newlines in the output stream:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FILE *fp = NULL;        
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "rb");        
    do
    {   // pull next char, break on EOF, subst '\n' on 0.
        int ch = fgetc(fp);
        if (EOF == ch)
            break;
        if (0 == ch)
            ch = '\n';
        fputc(ch, stdout);
    } while (true);

    fclose(fp);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the file is not a text file (that is, if it contains non-printable ASCII characters), treat it as binary.

Rather than reading a "line" at a time (which is a text file concept), read in a buffer at a time (e.g. 1024 characters at a time).

Output each character that you read one at a time, unless you encounter whatever line delimiter the file uses (e.g. the "null" character in your question).  When that character is encountered, output a newline instead.

You open a file in binary mode by including the "b" flag, e.g.

```
FILE *fp = fopen("dog.txt", "rb");
```

Use [fread](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fread/) to read data one buffer at a time.

```
n = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), BUFFER_SIZE, source);
```

Comment: if there is binary in the file apart from the unusual line terminator, you'll also want to map the non-printable characters. Without mapping them, printing to screen can cause all sort of strange things to happen when the data happens to look like control characters and such. The while(fgets) idiom breaks on null characters, as the returned character (null) turns into an unwanted termination of the loop (the condition turns false when data is null). So anyway, while(!EOF) or similar is the prudent loop.

Comment: Note that sizeof(char) is 1 by definition. So just use 1.

Comment: @WilliamMorris: Yes, but I prefer not to use "magic constants" when explaining something.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between "text" file handling and any other file handling is that the "text" functions assume certain things (for example, that \n is a separator). If that's not the case for you, you obviously cannot use the "text" manipulation functions. You do `fread`, and parse the content yourself.